# Finding generators for the kernel of $K[X,Y]\to K[T^3,T^5]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Let $K$ be a field with char$(K)\neq 3.$

Let $\phi:K[X,Y]\to K[T^3,T^5]\subset K[T]$ be the $K$-hom such that $\phi(X)=T^3$ and $\phi(Y)=T^5.$

Problem: Find generators for $\ker\phi.$

---

Attempt: It is clear that $Y^3-X^5 \in \ker\phi.$ I claim that, in fact, we have $\ker\phi = (Y^3-X^5).$

This follows if I can show that there are no non-zero elements in $\ker\phi$ of degree in $Y$ less than 3.

Suppose that $f_0(X)Y^2+f_1(X)Y+f_2(X) \in \ker\phi;$ that is,

$$(1) \hspace{1em} f_0(T^3)T^{10}+f_1(T^3)T^5+f_2(T^3)=0 \text{ in } K[T].$$

Let $L$ be an extension of $K$ which has a primitive 3rd root of unity, say $\omega.$ Then from (1), we have

$$(2) \hspace{1em} \omega f_0(T^3)T^{10}+\omega^2f_1(T^3)T^5+f_2(T^3)=0 \text{ in } L[T],$$

$$(3) \hspace{1em} \omega^2f_0(T^3)T^{10}+\omega f_1(T^3)T^5+f_2(T^3)=0 \text{ in } L[T],$$

where (2) comes from $T\mapsto \omega T$ and (3) comes from $T\mapsto \omega^2 T.$ Adding (1), (2), and (3) yields
$$3f_2(T^3)=0$$
and hence that $f_2(X)=0.$ We are thus reduced to
$$f_0(T^3)T^5+f_1(T^3)=0.$$
A similar procedure to the above shows that $f_1(X)=0$ and hence that $f_0(X)=0.$   $\;\;$ Q.E.D.

---

I would be very grateful if someone could check my argument (and possibly offer different approachs). Many thanks!

Comment: A different approach: $f_0(T^3)T^{10}+f_1(T^3)T^5+f_2(T^3)=0 \text{ in } K[T]$ leads immediately to $f_0=f_1=f_2=0$. Why? Because $3i_0+10\ne3i_1+5\ne3i_2$ (these are the powers of $T$ in $f_0(T^3)T^{10}$, $f_1(T^3)T^5$, resp. $f_2(T^3)$). Of course, the characteristic of $K$ plays no role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine for me. I'll propose another approach which requires no hypothesis on the characteristic (unless I missed something!).

$\ker \phi$ is a prime ideal of $K[X,Y]$, and it is not a maximal ideal since $\operatorname{Im}\phi=K[T^3,T^5]$ is not a field. So it's a prime ideal of height $1$, and in the U.F.D. $K[X,Y]$, it is generated by an irreducible element. Hence all we have to show is $Y^3-X^5$ is irreducible.

If it were not, it would have a linear factor in $Y$, say $Y-P(X)$, and we could write $\;X^5=P(X)^3$ in the polynomial ring $K[X]$. This can't happen as $\deg P(X)^3$ is multiple of $3$.

Comment: Ah yes! Very nice :) Thank you!

Comment: Was the hypothesis char$K\neq3$ given, or did you add it for your proof? That's what disturbs me.

Comment: Ah, don't worry - I added it. I was practicing this type of problem and making up my own examples so I felt free to weaken the hypothesis very slightly :)